# lua database insert - prepared statement

Tags: lua

```
  require "luasql.mysql" 
  instance:name(profile:id());

  env = assert (luasql.mysql())
  con = assert (env:connect("fxcm", "root", "admin"))
  con:execute([[INSERT INTO pet values('swaroop',"12")]]);
```

I would like to use prepared statement like in java. I found some references like `conn:prepare(statement)` in

https://realtimelogic.com/ba/doc/en/lua/luasql.html link.

But got no clue how to construct the statement. Please help me.

Comment: What don't you understand? The docs say that it takes a statement and returns a cursor object, and that cursor object also has documentation.

Answer (score 0):

https://realtimelogic.com/ba/doc/en/lua/luasql.html Is a barracudas module not [LuaSQL](https://github.com/keplerproject/luasql) from kepler prorject. I didn't find source from this server.
Original LuaSQL does not support prepared query (yet?).
I use [ODBC](https://github.com/moteus/lua-odbc) library to do that

```
local odbc = require "odbc.dba"

local cnn = odbc.Connect{
  Driver ='{MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}';
  db='test';
  uid='root';
};

local stmt = cnn:prepare"INSERT INTO pet values(:NAME,:AGE)"

stmt:exec{NAME = "swaroop", AGE = 12}
```

You can also checkout [LuaDBI](https://code.google.com/p/luadbi) library to native MySQL support.